# UIActivityViewController Calls ViewWillAppear but not ViewWillDisappear

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am finding that a call to `UIActivityViewController` is not calling `ViewWillDisappear` but when a user returns from the VC, it does call `ViewWillAppear`.  This process is 2-steps as at first it brings up a half screen to allow the user to select things like text or email.  Canceling here returns to the calling VC with no call to `ViewWillAppear`.  This is fine.  However, if you select a communication option like text, the VC is replaced with a full screen texting VC that never calls `ViewWillDisappear`.

I could call `ViewWillDisappear` manually, however, doing so I would not know if the user selected to "cancel" on the smaller half-screen prior to the full screen transition.

The code that calls the ActivityVC is as follows:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:shareAray 
                                                applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any reason why `ViewWillDisappear` is not called when returning does call `ViewWillAppear`? Anyway to know if the user hits "cancel" on the smaller half-screen just prior so that I don't call `ViewWillDisappear` myself unless they continue to the actual full screen share?

Comment: How would you know `viewWillAppear:` is called? You don't have a `UIActivityViewController` subclass being instantiated here. Or is this just a demo of how you instantiate your subclass?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  The above code is used to call the UIActivityVC.  I place a break point on the calling VC's ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear.  When I return from the activityController (after going to the full screen message not the half-screen question about messaging options) ViewWillAppear is called (again as caught by the break point).

Comment: And you're setting these breakpoints at `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` on the `UIViewController` pointed to by `self`?

Comment: Yes, remember ViewWillAppear is being called and caught by the breakpoint.  ViewWillDisappear should work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gutblender indicated through our exchange above, UIActivityVC is not calling ViewWillDisappear due to the modalPresentationStyle.  It doesn't feel like Apple is handling this right as when it does transition to a full screen it should call ViewWillDisappear.  However, since it doesn't I had to call it myself.  That said and it is not just a matter of calling ViewWillDisappear because the first screen Apple shows (a little half screen to pick the communication option) will NOT call ViewWillAppear or ViewWillDisappear if the user cancels at that stage.  If they don't and move on, even if they cancel on the messaging screen which displays next, the presenting VC's ViewWillAppear is called with ViewWillDisappear never having been called.  So, to keep the calls to ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear equal (I have NSNotification objects that I don't want registered more than once) I am using the below code.

```
[self viewWillDisappear:YES];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:shareAray
                                                                                    applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];

    [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        if (!activityType || UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            [self viewWillAppear:YES];
        }
    }];
```

By way of explanation, `activityType` above will be NULL if the user cancels out of the first little half screen.  If they move on to the next screen (which is the full screen) it will contain an activityType even if they cancel.  So, if they cancel on the first small half-screen I have to force viewWillAppear to be called otherwise the regular process will automatically call viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

The method `presentViewController` will cause `viewWillAppear:` to be called on the **presented** view controller, and subsequently `viewWillDisappear:` will be called on the **presented** view controller when it is about to disappear. To intercept these calls, subclass `UIActivityViewController` and implement overrides to those methods.

As for how to tell if the user canceled or not, I would suggest doing it the way it's commonly done for Windows Forms. Add a public "dialog result" property of some kind (probably exposed as `get`-only) that is set to one of some range of values so the calling (or *presenting*) view controller can tell why the called (or `self.presentedViewController` in this case) dismissed when it did.

Comment: It's not clear to me what I need to do here.  If I am able to intercept ViewWillAppear why would I not be able to intercept ViewWillDisappear?  Based on the behavior of the app, I know ViewWillDisappear isn't being called.

Comment: You said above the presenting view controller is not getting `viewWillDisappear` called. But why would that get called? It's not going to disappear. What will disappear, however, is the **presented** view controller. So use a subclass where you override and intercept those methods. On the presenting VC, the reason `viewWillAppear:` will get called as the presented VC disappears because I presume the presenting VC's view is about to re-appear.

Comment: Thanks, I am understanding where you are coming from.  My understanding was that the presenting VC would disappear as it is being replaced by the UIActivityVC.  You are suggesting that it is not which is what appears to be happening.  Not sure why that is.  The problem is that I have NSNotification objects in ViewWillAppear.  They are removed in ViewWillDisappear all in the presenting VC.  So in this case ViewWillAppear is adding the observer again without it having been removed in ViewWillDisappear.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not 100% on whether the presenter will disappear or not. It may depending on the presenter's `modalPresentationStyle`; perhaps if it's set to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen `. But the real way to tell is with your own `UIActivityViewController` subclass.

Comment: You've just hit on it.  I experimented with the presentation style and setting it to full screen does enable ViewWillDisappear.  The problem seems to be due to the first VC that UIActivityVC calls is a little half screen selection.  If you go on from there when it does call a full screen version, it doesn't register as such.  When you set it to be full right away, it does.  I do not like the look it causes though by setting it full screen so I solved in a different way which I will post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you retain a strong reference to the activity controller? Maybe it's getting released. Try declaring the controller inside your class.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a retain issue.  It looks like Apple is not calling viewWillDisappear because the first VC is only a little half screen.  As this is all done in one call there isn't a way to do something different between the two screens.  When the user does move to the full messaging screen I think Apple needs to call viewWillDisappear.